# Determine the value of $k$ so that the points P(-8,10), Q(2,-4), and R(22,k) are collinear

Tags: linear-algebra

I think this is an extremely simple problem, but my answer is different from the answer sheet. I wonder whether I miss some concept. My answer is 24, but the answer sheet is 12.

> Determine the value of $k$ so that the points P(-8,10), Q(2,-4), and R(22,k) are collinear.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us what you did to arrive at your answer.

Comment: I think it should be $-24$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. For things to be collinear, their slopes have to be the same. The slope of $PQ=\frac{-7}{5}$. Then the slope of $QR $ must equal the slope of $PQ$.$\frac{k+4}{20}=\frac{-7}{5}$. Therefore, $k=-32$.

Comment: Read this if you need more help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405966/if-i-have-three-points-is-there-an-easy-way-to-tell-if-they-are-collinear.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $P$, $Q$, and $R$ are colinear if and only if the vectors $\vec{PQ}$ and $\vec{PR}$ are parallel. But two vectors are parallel if and only if their cross product is the zero vector. Hence $P$, $Q$, and $R$ are colinear if and only if
$$
\vec 0=\vec{PQ}\times\vec{PR}=\left(10,\,-14,\,0\right)\times \left(30,\,k - 10,\,0\right)=\left(0,\,0,\,10 \, k + 320\right)
$$
Since $10\,k+320=0$ if and only if $k=-32$, it follows that $P$, $Q$, and $R$ are colinear if and only if $k=-32$.