# The most efficient way to calculate the area of the triangle

Tags: area

What is the most efficient way to calculate the area of the triangle enclosed in the lines with equation $y= x+2, 2y= -3x + 7$ and $x=5$?

I constructed all the lines and then calculated the sides of the triangle by using Pythagorean theorem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find the points $A$ and $B$ where the other two lines meet $x=5$. The length of $AB$ is the **base** (you may have to twist your neck a bit). Now compute the height by finding where the other two lines meet.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516219/finding-out-the-area-of-a-triangle-if-the-coordinates-of-the-three-vertices-are

Comment: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheAreaOfATriangleUsingADeterminant/ using determinants

Answer (score 0):

With that problem?  The line x = 5 makes things much easier.
Find the coordinates of the vertexes.  Make the line x = 5 "the base"  and it should be simple enough to find the height.

Generalizing this just a little bit.  If you did not have a line that was parallel to the coordinate axes.  Find the vertex.  Make a rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes, with the vertexes on the rectangle.  There are 3 right triangles "in the box" that are not the triangle you are looking for.  Calculate the area of the box, and subtract the area of these 3 right triangles.

Comment: Oh, of course. I made it myself harder. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the formula for the distance of a point from a line, and only want to use the formula for the distance between two points, you can use [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula).