# Calculate area of triangle in space given points

Tags: vectors, area

[Problem 5. a)](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02-multivariable-calculus-fall-2007/exams/prac1a.pdf) Find the area of the space triangle with vertices $P_0, P_1, P_2$:

$$ P_0 = (2,1,0),\ \ P_1=(1,0,1),\ \ P_2=(2,-1,1) $$

My current solution is to use $\frac{1}{2}\Big|(P_1-P_0)×(P_2-P_0)\Big|$, which is great but leaves me wanting for a more elegant solution similar to [taking the determinant for triangles in the plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1388253/3157).

Is there a better solution, either in terms of elegance or ease of mental calculation?

Comment: The linked question answers in 2D, you could do the same for 3D.

Comment: Isn't $\left( {{P_1} - {P_0}} \right) \times \left( {{P_2} - {P_0}} \right)$ a vector?

Comment: @IvanAbraham: Whoops. Indeed it is. Edited.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: That's what I thought, but I haven't yet been able to wrap my head around how you would do that.

Comment: $$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
x_0 & x_1 & x_2 \\
y_0 & y_1 & y_2 \\
z_0 & z_1 & z_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
isn't square, so has no determinant.

Answer (score 1):

I like your solution, but another way to do it would be to compute the lengths of the sides using the distance formula, and then use Heron's formula.

http://www.mathopenref.com/heronsformula.html

Answer (score 1):

Even if we stick with cross products, we can make the result considerably more elegant in the sense of making the symmetry in indices manifest, viz.$$(P_1-P_0)\times (P_2-P_0)=P_1\times P_2-P_1\times P_0-P_0\times P_2+P_0\times P_0\\=P_0\times P_1+P_1\times P_2+P_2\times P_0.$$