# What does the determinant form of triangle area imply "transformation-wise"?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, determinant, area

I have a basic grasp of matrices and I was just wondering to which transformation does this matrix correspond?
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 &  y_1 & 1 \\ x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\ x_3 & y_3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

It is used for calculating the area of a triangle with three known vertices as, $Area= \frac{1}{2}\det{A}$. Why are we transforming each basis vector to the $z=1$ plane?

Comment: Related questions (which explain the formula, although I don't know if they answer your specific question about an interpretation): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299352/show-that-the-area-of-a-triangle-is-given-by-this-determinant, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516219/finding-out-the-area-of-a-triangle-if-the-coordinates-of-the-three-vertices-are

Comment: @HansLundmark They are similar but don't answer my question which focuses on intuition rather than proofs.