# Geometric interpretation of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

I'm interested in knowing some geometric interpretation of matrices. Can you suggest any lecture note or textbook or anything else about it?
I've just finished an undergraduate course in linear algebra, so do not suggest any linear algebra book please, I just want to know more about this topic.
Examples of what a mean by "geometric interpretation" are [click1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37398/what-is-the-geometric-interpretation-of-the-transpose)
and [click2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598258/determinant-of-transpose/636198#636198).

Answer (score 1):

The first book(s) that come to my mind are [Geometric linear algebra (2 vols](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9812560874)). These books cover a lot of material but since you have already taken a course on the subject, I feel you may fast forward many parts.