# What is the proof that det(A) = det(A transpose)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why det(A) = det(A transpose)?
Can you give me the proof?

Comment: Search for "determinant of transpose"... https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Transpose

Comment: There is also [Determinant of transpose?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/598258) with a geometric proof.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Develop $\det A$ along the first line, $\det {}^{\mathrm t\!}A$ along  the first column and apply the inductive hypothesis.