# Explanation regarding determinant derivation

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have a question about the second paragraph of the following excerpt, which is taken from p.115 of *Introductory Mathematics: Algebra and Analysis* by Geoff Smith:

> In the light of these properties of determinant, we calculate $|X|$ again where $X=\left(x_{i j}\right)$ is a 3 by 3 matrix. Instead of using Definition $4.7$, let us see how far we get in an attempt to evaluate $|X|$ using Remark 4.3.
>
> Think of $X$ as a column vector, its entries being row vectors. Let the $i$-th row be $\mathbf{x}_{i}$. Now let $\mathbf{e}_{i}$ be the $i$-th row of $I_{n}$, so that $\mathbf{x}_{i}=\sum_{j} x_{i j} \mathbf{e}_{j}$. We now use property (c) in Remark $4.3$ (*determinant being a multilinear function*) to find that $|X|$ is
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> x_{11} x_{22} x_{33}\left|\begin{array}{lll}
> 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1
> \end{array}\right|+x_{11} x_{23} x_{32}\left|\begin{array}{lll}
> 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0
> \end{array}\right|\\
> +x_{12} x_{23} x_{31}\left|\begin{array}{lll}
> 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> 1 & 0 & 0
> \end{array}\right|+x_{12} x_{21} x_{33}\left|\begin{array}{lll}
> 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1
> \end{array}\right|\\
> +x_{13} x_{21} x_{32}\left|\begin{array}{lll}
> 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0
> \end{array}\right|+x_{13} x_{22} x_{31}\left|\begin{array}{lll}
> 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0 & 0
> \end{array}\right|
> \end{aligned}
> $$

Specifically, my question is what is the connection between the second paragraph and the formula below it. How do the authors get from

> Now let $\mathbf{e}_{i}$ be the $i$-th row of $I_{n}$, so that
> $\mathbf{x}_{i}=\sum_{j} x_{i j} \mathbf{e}_{j}$.

to the expression for the determinant of $X$?

Extra (the whole book: https://docdro.id/gnu93vl):

**Definition 4.7**
Suppose that $A=\left(a_{i j}\right)$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix. We define the determinant $|A|$ inductively. Thus we assume that we know how to calculate a determinant $|X|$ where $X$ is an $n-1$ by $n-1$ matrix, and start the induction off by defining the determinant of a 1 by 1 matrix $(a)$ to be $a$.

Pick any row of $A$, say the $i$-th row. We will work out $|A|$ by using the entries of the $i$-th row of $A$ and the determinants of some $n-1$ by $n-1$ matrices. For each entry $a_{i j}$ in the $i$-th row, let $A_{i j}$ be the $n-1$ by $n-1$ matrix obtained by striking out the $i$-th row and $j$-th column of $A$. Let $c_{i j}=(-1)^{i+j}\left|A_{i j}\right|$. Now let $|A|=\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{i j} c_{i j}$.

**Remark 4.3 (c)**
The map is multilinear in each of the $n$ row vector variables. In other words, if you choose $i$ in the range $1 \leq i \leq n$ and keep all arguments fixed except the variable in position $i$, you obtain a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. To be explicit, if we fix all rows except one, determinant defines a function $\alpha$ from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by varying the distinguished row. To say that $\alpha$ is linear is to assert that
$$
\alpha(\lambda \mathbf{x}+\mu \mathbf{y})=\lambda \alpha(\mathbf{x})+\mu \alpha(\mathbf{y}) \forall \lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}, \forall \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}
$$

Comment: Remark 4.3, definition 4.7,... in *which book*?

Comment: see the Wikipedia article on the Leibniz determinant formula, anyway. It's terse but it should cover everything

Comment: @FShrike Introductory Mathematics: Algebra and Analysis, page 115

Comment: Tell the post that, rather than me specifically. My point was, it’s hard to answer your question unless we have a copy of this book to hand. Try to add everything relevant, including their proof up to where you got stuck

Comment: @FShrike I agree, it could indeed be harder to answer. I tried to keep the post as short as possible and hence omitted some parts, but nevertheless I now added the missing text as well as shared the link to the book.

Comment: The matrix addition you see is the result of applying the multi-linearity of the determinant. These properties are independent of how the determinant is defined. Do you understand the difference between linearity and multi-linearity?

Comment: @JohnDouma I suppose I do, here is a quite nice explanation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403735/why-is-determinant-a-multilinear-function but I still don't understand how the authors derived the above. Perhaps you have an idea?

Comment: @Treex see my answer. Hope you will understand.

Comment: @LostinSpace Perfect, thank you! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us illustrate by examples.

---

${{\color{red}{2×2 \space Matrix }}}$

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} x_{11}&x_{12}\\x_{21}&x_{22}\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{align}\color{blue}{\text{Row} \space 1} : x_1&=\begin{bmatrix}x_{11} &x_{12}\end{bmatrix}\\&=x_{11}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + x_{12}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\&=x_{11}e_1+x_{12}e_{2}\end{align}$

$\begin{align}\color{green}{\text{Row} \space 2} : x_2&=\begin{bmatrix}x_{21} &x_{22}\end{bmatrix}\\&=x_{21}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + x_{22}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\&=x_{21}e_1+x_{22}e_{2}\end{align}$

---

$\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix}\color{blue}{\text{Row}1}\\\color{green}{\text{Row }2}\end{vmatrix}&= \begin{vmatrix}   x_{11}e_1+x_{12}e_{2}  \\\color{green}{\text{Row }2}\end{vmatrix}\\& {\overset{\color{red}1}{=}}\begin{vmatrix}   x_{11}e_1  \\\color{green}{\text{Row }2}\end{vmatrix} +\begin{vmatrix}   x_{12}e_{2}  \\\color{green}{\text{Row }2}\end{vmatrix}\\&{\overset{\color{red}2}{=}}x_{11}\begin{vmatrix}   e_1  \\x_{21}e_1+x_{22}e_2\end{vmatrix} +x_{12}\begin{vmatrix}   e_{2}  \\x_{21}e_1+x_{22}e_2\end{vmatrix} \\&{\overset{\color{red}3}{=}}x_{11}x_{21} \begin{vmatrix} e_1\\e_1\end{vmatrix}+x_{11}x_{22} \begin{vmatrix} e_1\\e_2\end{vmatrix}+
x_{11}x_{21} \begin{vmatrix} e_2\\e_1\end{vmatrix}+x_{12}x_{22} \begin{vmatrix} e_2\\e_2\end{vmatrix}\\&  {\overset{\color{red}4}{=}}
 x_{11}x_{21} \cdot 0 +x_{11}x_{22} \cdot 1+ x_{12}x_{21} \cdot (-1)+x_{12}x_{22} \cdot 0 \\&=  x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}
\end{align}$

---

$\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix}x_{11}&x_{12}\\x_{21}&x_{22}\end{vmatrix}&=\begin{vmatrix}x_{11}&0\\x_{21}&x_{22}\end{vmatrix}+   \begin{vmatrix}0&x_{12}\\x_{21}&x_{22}\end{vmatrix}\\&=\begin{vmatrix}x_{11}&0\\x_{21}&0\end{vmatrix}+ \begin{vmatrix}x_{11}&0\\0&x_{22}\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}0&x_{12}\\x_{21}&0\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}0&x_{12}\\0&x_{22}\end{vmatrix}\\&=0+x_{11}x_{22} \begin{vmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{vmatrix}+x_{12}x_{21} \begin{vmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{vmatrix}+0\\&=x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}
\end{align}$

---

${\overset{\color{red}1}{=}}:\text{Additivity in Row }1$

${\overset{\color{red}2}{=}}:\text{Homogeneity  in Row }1$

${\overset{\color{red}3}{=}}:\text{Linearity in Row }2$

${\overset{\color{red}4}{=}}:\begin{cases}\text{Two equal Row }:\det(A) =0 \\\text{Two Row exchange  }:\det(A') =-\det(A)\end{cases}$

---

Extension for $3×3$ matrix is similar.

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} x_{11}&x_{12}&x_{13}\\x_{21}&x_{22}&x_{23}\\x_{31}&x_{32}&x_{33}\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{align}\color{blue}{\text{Row} \space 1} : x_1&=\begin{bmatrix}x_{11} &x_{12}&x_{13}\end{bmatrix}\\&=x_{11}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 &0\end{bmatrix} + x_{12}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 &0\end{bmatrix}+x_{13}\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1  \end{bmatrix} \\&=x_{11}e_1+x_{12}e_{2}+x_{13}e_3\end{align}$

$\begin{align}\color{green}{\text{Row} \space 2} : x_2&=\begin{bmatrix}x_{21} &x_{22}&x_{23}\end{bmatrix}\\&=x_{21}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 &0\end{bmatrix} + x_{22}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 &0\end{bmatrix}+x_{23}\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1  \end{bmatrix} \\&=x_{21}e_1+x_{22}e_{2}+x_{23}e_3\end{align}$

$\begin{align}\color{brown}{\text{Row} \space 3} : x_3&=\begin{bmatrix}x_{31} &x_{32}&x_{33}\end{bmatrix}\\&=x_{31}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 &0\end{bmatrix} + x_{32}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 &0\end{bmatrix}+x_{33}\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1  \end{bmatrix} \\&=x_{31}e_1+x_{32}e_{2}+x_{33}e_3\end{align}$

Now expand linearly and compute $3! $ determinants .