# Adjugate vs transpose of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, transpose

Adjugate(classical adjoint) of a matrix https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix is the inverse rotation without scaling. When a matrix is multipled by its inverse, off diagonal entries are zero and diagonal entries have the value scaled by matrix.

But according to the Matt's answer in [Geometric interpretation of $\det(A^T) = \det(A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598258/geometric-interpretation-of-detat-deta) , transpose too is stated as inverse rotation without scaling. So adjugate is equal to transpose? Which is clearly wrong. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: if $A$ is a matrix with real entries, its adjoint and its transpose are the same thing.

Comment: @Jay What exactly do you mean by "adjoint of a matrix is the inverse rotation without the scaling"? Also, in the second sentence it looks like that "adjoint" that you are thinking of is the [classical adjoint (AKA adjugate)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) rather than the notion of "adjoint" discussed in the link.

Comment: @Jay At no point in the answer does Matt say that the transpose is "inverse rotation without scaling". If you point to where you think Matt says that in the answer, we might have a better idea of what you actually have in mind.

Comment: @Ben In the title of the third part

Comment: Adjugate, transpose, adjoint, inverse: all different but interrelated concepts.

Comment: @A rural reader can you elaborate on the difference between transpose and adjugate. Like adjugate inverts the rotation without scaling. Similarly how do I interpret transpose?

Comment: @Jay So “keeping” the scaling is the same as doing something “without the scaling”? I’m trying to figure out what you mean by “without the scaling”.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A^*$ be the [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) of $A$. The defining property of the adjoint is that it satisfies $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,A^*y\rangle$ for some inner product. For a real vector space this will be the transpose however for a complex vector space it will be the conjugate transpose.

To see this let’s restrict ourselves to real vector spaces with $x$ and $y$ column vectors so that we can represent the Euclidean [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) with matrix multiplication as $\langle x,y \rangle = x^Ty$. This means we have $$\langle Ax,y\rangle = (Ax)^Ty = x^TA^Ty=\langle x , A^Ty\rangle $$

so the adjoint is the transpose. The complex case can be proved in the same way although the geometric meaning is less clear. Note that there is a nice relationship between the inner product, its [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)), and the [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Normed_vector_spaces) it induces. This allows the geometric interpretation given to the adjoint since the inner product is directly related to distances and thus scaling.