# How do I find k so that this rank is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & 2 & -2 \\
        1 & 1 & -1 \\
        -1 & 2 & k \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Find the values *k* for which rank(A) = 3
From what I have tried myself, I have brought it down to row-echelon form where it looks something like this:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & -1 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & k+2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Through various row operations, but I seem to be stuck on whether or not I'm doing the right thing. Thanks!

To start:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & 2 & -2 \\
        1 & 1 & -1 \\
        -1 & 2 & k \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Interchanging Rows 1 and 2.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & -1 \\
        3 & 2 & -2 \\
        -1 & 2 & k \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

then, Row 2 minus 3 times Row 1 and Row 3 plus Row 1.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & -1 \\
        0 & -1 & 1 \\
        0 & 3 & k-1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

then,  multiply Row 2 by (-1)

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & -1 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 \\
        0 & 3 & k-1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Finally, Row 3 minus 3 times Row 2.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & -1 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & k+2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I have not verified that the final form is correct, but what you have described is a good way to solve the problem. Reduce the matrix so that you either obtain the reduced row echelon form, or a form that is close enough (so that you can read off the rank). From the second matrix you have (which I have not verified is correct) you could conclude that the rank of the matrix is 3 if and only if $k\neq -2$.

Comment: Oh no. That's bad and embarrassing.

Comment: I also keep trying doing the same legal row operations and I keep getting the same result. (I'm interchanging rows 1 and 2, then Row 2 - 3Row 1, then Row 3 + Row 1, then Row - 3Row 2).

Comment: Let me write the all my steps, hold on. Because its the second row minus 3 times the first row.

Comment: I have added the changes and showed my steps.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:-
Rank$=3$ iff $\det(A)\ne 0$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you row reduced correctly, you should just check what happens when $k+2=0$, and when $k+2 \neq 0$, recalling that $rk=3 \iff det(A) \neq 0$.

A nice way to see this is by checking what happens to the [determinant under row operations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598219/effect-of-elementary-row-operations-on-determinant) and checking that the determinant of the original matrix has a zero if and only if the reduced matrix does.

Note that the determinant of your row reduced matrix is $k+2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align*}
\det(A)&=3(k+2)-2(k-1)-2(2+1)\\
&=k+2
\end{align*}$

So $\det(A)=0  \iff k=-2$.