# Finding eigenvalues of $4 \times 4$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
          1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

tried to find Eigen value for this matrix 
$\begin{bmatrix}
        1-\lambda & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 &  1-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 &  1-\lambda  & 0 \\
          1 & 0 & 0 &  1-\lambda  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$
and got $\lambda^4-4\lambda^3+6\lambda^2-4\lambda$ 
so $\lambda(\lambda^3-4\lambda^2+6\lambda-4)$ 
but I tried to factorize $\lambda^3-4\lambda^2+6\lambda-4$ got $(\lambda-2)<br>\lambda^2-2\lambda+2$ and cannot factorize $\lambda^2-2\lambda+2$ .

 is my calculation wrong? 
thanks!!

Comment: Try computing that determinant again: your characteristic polynomial is incorrect.

Comment: @amd thanks i forgot,  this method only applicable in matrix 3x3 and 2x2 only

Comment: @Vixf  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
\begin{equation}
A-\lambda I = \begin{bmatrix}
        1-\lambda & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 &  1-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 &  1-\lambda  & 0 \\
          1 & 0 & 0 &  1-\lambda  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
\det(A-\lambda I) = [(1-\lambda)^2-1]^2
\end{equation}
Thus the eigenvalues are $\lambda = 0, 2$ with multiplicity 2.
To be more precise, computing the determinant based on the first column gives
\begin{align}
\det(A-\lambda I) &= (1-\lambda)\det \begin{bmatrix} 1-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1- \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1-\lambda \end{bmatrix} - \det 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1-\lambda & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
&=(1-\lambda)\{(1-\lambda)[(1-\lambda)^2-1]\} -[(1-\lambda)^2-1]\\
&=[(1-\lambda)^2-1]^2
\end{align}

For your convenience, let me compute the 3x3 matrix determinant.
\begin{align}
\det \begin{bmatrix} 1-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1- \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1-\lambda \end{bmatrix}
&= (1-\lambda) \det \begin{bmatrix} 1-\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 1-\lambda \end{bmatrix}
- 1 \cdot \det \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1-\lambda \end{bmatrix} \\
&= (1-\lambda)(1-\lambda)^2 - (1-\lambda) = (1-\lambda)[(1-\lambda)^2-1]
\end{align}

Comment: thanks but I don't understand this method, what method is this? and how can you pull $(1-\lambda)$?

Comment: @Vixf Please take a look on this link: [link](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-determinant.html)

Comment: Isn't the determinant of the second 3×3 matrix with the opposite sign?

Comment: @user87690 You are correct. I just noticed and fixed it.

Comment: @induction601 I got the point but how can you make the first row or first column all become zero? in order to pull out $(1-\lambda)$

Comment: @Vixf Actually, you don't need to make the first row or column have more zeros. Please find the my edited answer. I added more details.

Comment: @induction601 hello i got it but is it possible to reduce the matrix to reduced echelon first or make it more simpler and then do the cofactor expansion? Will it change the determinant?

Answer (score 3):

By permuting columns and rows you can immediately see the following:
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}
1-λ & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1-λ & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 - λ & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 - λ
\end{pmatrix} = \det\begin{pmatrix}
1-λ&1&0&0\\
1&1-λ&0&0\\
0&0&1-λ&1\\
0&0&1&1-λ
\end{pmatrix} = \det\begin{pmatrix}
1-λ&1\\
1&1-λ
\end{pmatrix}^2 = ((1-λ)^2 - 1)^2 = (λ^2 - 2λ)^2 = λ^2(λ-2)^2
$$

Comment: thanks but I don't understand what permuting columns and row here? do you exchange it?

Comment: By permuting rows or columns of a matrix, the determinant is multiplied by $1$ or $-1$ depending on the sign of the permutation. Here we used $(2\ 3\ 4)$ on both row and columns, but it is an even permutation so the determinant does not change.

Comment: in first column, how did you convert it to  $(1 1-\lambda 0 0)$?

Comment: As I said, by cycling the last three columns and then cycling the last three rows.

Answer (score 2):

as the matrix has rank=2 you have: $$\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$$

in this case you can easily find the 2 no trivial eigenvectors by inspection

$$e_3=(1,0,0,1)$$
$$e_4=(0,1,1,0)$$

at which correspond the following eigenvalues:

$$\lambda_3=2$$
$$\lambda_4=2$$

Comment: hello thanks, so I mean did you try to reduced the matriks to row echelon form? and also convert it to diagonal matrix, and the diagonal matrix is the Eigen value. ?

Comment: That the matrix has rank=2 is immediate because row1=row4 and row2=row3, thus you must have 2 null eigenvalues. From inspection its easy in this case to find the other 2 eigenvectors and the corresponding eigenvalues not equal to $0$. It is not a general method but it is important to recognize these simpler cases.

Comment: thanks, I got that the rank is two and row 3 and 4 is null, but how to find $\lambda_3 =2 and \lambda_4=2$?

Comment: what do you mean with "row 3 and 4 is null"? To find $\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_4$, from the definition of eigenvalues: $Ae_3=2e_3=\lambda_3e_3$ and  $Ae_4=2e_4=\lambda_4e_4$

Comment: ok so using $Ax=\lambda x$, did you get the Eigen value by substituted one of Eigen vector as x? and null space here means, that there are 2 null Eigen value , and the geometric multiplicities of Eigen value will be two ?

Comment: @Vixf yes exactly!

Comment: thanks but there is problem that i need to find the Eigen value first in order to find the Eigen vector, so for problem like this ,is it better to solve it using cofactor expansion method to find determinant?

Comment: yef of course, but believe me, it's important that you recognize these simpler case to check the results :)

Comment: @gemusi okay thankyou so much :)!!!

Comment: @gemusi sorry can i ask again,can you explain how did you get the eigen vector ? row 3 and row 4 will be all zero, so there is only row 1 and row 2, then did you use Ax=0 to find the eigen vector?

Answer (score 2):

I will just point out that it is quite easy to notice that:

- $(1,0,0,-1)A=(0,1,-1,0)A=0$
- $(1,0,0,1)A=(2,0,0,2)$ and $(0,1,1,0)A=(0,2,2,0)$

So with a bit of guesswork we can see that $0$ and $2$ are eigenvalues of (geometric) multiplicity two. (I think that since this is a very simple matrix with several symmetries, it is not that difficult to spot at least some eigenvector for these eigenvalues.)

Looking at some of those eigenvectors can also give you a reasonable idea which row operations could be used to calculated the charateristic polynomials. For example:

$$\det\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
 1-\lambda& 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1-\lambda & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1-\lambda
\end{array}\right)=
\det\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
 2-\lambda& 0 & 0 & 2-\lambda \\
  0 & 2-\lambda & 2-\lambda & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1-\lambda & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1-\lambda
\end{array}\right)=
(2-\lambda)^2\det\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1-\lambda & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1-\lambda
\end{array}\right)=
(2-\lambda)^2\det\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -\lambda & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -\lambda
\end{array}\right)=(2-\lambda)^2\lambda^2$$

Comment: thanks got it! just want to ask one thing , if i want to use method cofactor expansion, can i reduce the matrix using row operation first then apply the cofactor expansion? will it change the matrix value?

Comment: and one more thing $(1,0,0,-1)A=(0,1,-1,0)A=0$ , how did you notice this?

Comment: @Vixf You can find details about effect of elementary row operations, for example, [on ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Effect_of_Elementary_Row_Operations_on_Determinant) and there is something even on this site: [Effect of elementary row operations on determinant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/598219)

Comment: thanks, but im just wondering, the usual procedure is to find characteristic polynomial, but here can you explain to me what do you mean by "quite easy to notice", in this problem, how could you notice the eigen vector without finding characteristic polynomial first? did you reduce the matrix to row echelon first and got the eigen vector?

Comment: @Vixf No, I just look at the matrix and noticed that if I subtract fourth row from the first one, I get zero. Similarly, you can notice that if you add the first and the fourth row, you get $2(1,0,0,1)$. Or, if this is easier to see, just look what happens if you look at sum of all rows. (If you are used to work with column vectors, you should look at columns instead. But since the matrix is symmetric, this does not make any difference.)

Comment: yes i mean,  $\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ i got this after substract third and fourth row from first and second row, but is this automatically become eigen vector(?) i see that the scalar is 2 and if i sum up the trace total will be 4, but how can i find the eigen vector without finding $\lambda$ first

Answer (score 1):

Check your determinant calculation.  I get $\lambda^4 - 4 \lambda^3 + 4 \lambda^2$, giving the eigenvalues $0$, $0$, $2$, and $2$.

Comment: thanks but I got the determinant calculation, $(1-\lambda)^4 -1$. is it true?

Comment: No, that is not the determinant.  See [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2541486/123905), where this computation is explained in detail.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix can be written $A=B+I$. Then $B$ is a permutation matrix corresponding to the permutation $(14)(23)$ and so $B^2=I$. Since $B\ne I$ and $B\ne -I$, the minimal polynomial of $B$ must be $X^2-1$. Hence, the eigenvalues of $B$ are $-1$ and $1$ and so the eigenvalues of $A$ are $-1+1$ and $1+1$, or $0$ and $2$.

It easy to see that the characteristic polynomial of $B$ is $(X^2-1)^2$ and so both eigenvalues of $B$ have multiplicity $2$ and so do the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You may try a simpler method, like Hamilton Caley method by using the traces:

$$\text{det}A = \frac{1}{24}\left\{(\text{tr} A)^4 - 6(\text{tr}A)^2\text{tr}(A^2) + 3(\text{tr}(A^2))^2 + 8\text{tr}(A^3)\text{tr}A - 6\text{tr}(A^4)\right\}$$

Anyway, as eigenvalues I got:

$$\{2; 2; 0; 0\}$$