# What do the column of 1's signify when calculating the area of an image using the determinant?

Tags: matrices

When calculating the area of an image such as that given by the three coordinates (4,3), (4,10), and (-4,-3), why when writing it out as a matrix is there an extra column of 1's?

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        4 & 3 & 1 \\
        4 & 10 & 1 \\
        -4 & -3 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
I understand that it is not possible to find the determinant of a non-square matrix, so my questions are:

**1)** Are 1's just used to make the matrix a square?
**2)** If so, is there any reason why 1's and not 0's are used?

Comment: This is a tangential comment, but it would be better to be more careful when stating what you are taking the area of. The title states that you are computing the "area of a matrix", which does not make sense because a matrix does not have an area. The question body states that you have to find the area of the three given coordinates, which also does not make sense. I believe your goal is to compute the area of the *triangle* whose vertices are the three given points.

Comment: You mean the area of the triangle determined by the three points ?

Comment: Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299352/show-that-the-area-of-a-triangle-is-given-by-this-determinant

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm more confused as to why 1's are used in the column rather than how to solve it

Comment: Perhaps a more intuitive answer is the result at the *end* of that link, that the area of the triangle is half of *that* determinant. Then the rest of the answer, read backwards, can be thought of as manipulating that result into a nicer form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to look at the ones.

Algebraically, we are using the properties of determinant to express the area of a triangle $T$ with vertices at $A : (x_1,y_1)$, $B : (x_2,y_2)$, $C : (x_3,y_3)$ in a simpler form:

$$\verb/Area/(T) = \frac12 
\left|
\begin{matrix}
x_2 - x_1 & y_2 - y_1\\
x_3 - x_1 & y_3 - y_1\\
\end{matrix}\right|
=
\frac12 
\left|
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
x_2 - x_1 & y_2 - y_1 & 1\\
x_3 - x_1 & y_3 - y_1 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right|
= \frac12
\left|
\begin{matrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1\\
x_2 & y_2 & 1\\
x_3 & y_3 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right|
$$

Geometrically, we can embed $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the plane $z = 1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The vertices of $T$ becomes the points $A' : (x_1,y_1,1)$, $B' : (x_1,y_2,1)$, $C' : (x_3,y_3,1)$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$. 
Let $T'$ be the tetrahedron spanned by $A', B', C'$ and origin $O : (0,0,0)$.
The area of $T$ is 3 times the volume of tetrahedron $T'$.
The volume of  $T'$ is $\frac16$ of the volume of the parallelepiped $P$ with one vertex at $O$ and spanned by the 3 vectors $A', B', C'$. Since the volume of a parallelepiped can be expressed as a cross product which equals to corresponding determinant, we have:

$$\verb/Area/(T) = 3\verb/Volume/(T') = \frac{3}{6}\verb/Volume/(P)
= \frac12
\left|
\begin{matrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1\\
x_2 & y_2 & 1\\
x_3 & y_3 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right|
$$
In certain sense, the introduction of ones here reflect the possibility
to express geometric relations for objects living on the plane as geometric relations on $\mathbb{R}^3$. It allows one to look at plane geometry problem from a completely different angle and offer us new insight how to solve a problem.