# co-ordinate geometry with constraints on triangles and a square

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Triangle ABC is right angled at A,AB = 2AC,A=(1,2),B= (-3,1) ACD is an equilateral triangle. The vertices of two triangles are in anticlockwise sense. BCEF is a square with vertices in clockwise sense. Find

a. Area of triangle ACF

b. Length of DE

c. Y co-ordinate of centroid of square BCEF

Comment: Did you try at least to draw a picture? Can you show it here?

Comment: Yes Sire I have drawn it

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points for uploading

Comment: Question a : You have first to show that the coord. of C are (3/2,0), then find coord. of E(5/2,5) and F(-5/2,6) then use the formula that gives the area of a triangle knowing the coord. of its vertices (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299352). Question c is easy. Question b looks a little more difficult.