# matrix $\left|\frac{1}{2} \left| \begin{array}{lll} x_{1} & y_{1} & 1 \\ x_{2} & y_{2} & 1 \\ x_{3} & y_{3} & 1 \end{array}\right|\right|$

Tags: matrices, determinant, triangles, analytic-geometry, area

I know that the area of a triangle is $\frac{1}{2}bh$ but today I learnt that to computing the area of a triangle using coordinates:
$$
\text { Area of } \triangle A B C=\left|\frac{1}{2} \left| \begin{array}{lll}
x_{1} & y_{1} & 1 \\
x_{2} & y_{2} & 1 \\
x_{3} & y_{3} & 1
\end{array}\right|\right|=\frac{1}{2}\left|\left[x_{1}\left(y_{2}-y_{3}\right)+x_{2}\left(y_{3}-y_{1}\right)+x_{3}\left(y_{1}-y_{2}\right)\right]\right|
$$

I came to know that this $\left|\frac{1}{2} \left| \begin{array}{lll} x_{1} & y_{1} & 1 \\ x_{2} & y_{2} & 1 \\ x_{3} & y_{3} & 1 \end{array}\right|\right|$ is called matrix. How did we get this matrix $\left|\frac{1}{2} \left| \begin{array}{lll} x_{1} & y_{1} & 1 \\ x_{2} & y_{2} & 1 \\ x_{3} & y_{3} & 1 \end{array}\right|\right|$? I am not able to understand this.

Comment: Do you know anything about determinants of matrices and their properties?

Comment: If not, then the best explanation is probably "that matrix determinant is shorthand for the product of $x_i$'s and $y_j$'s on the right" and you can try to get that product from various differences of areas of right triangles and rectangles.

Comment: Are you familiar with the cross product?  That is, we have $$|\vec a\times\vec b|=|\vec a||\vec b|\sin\theta,$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$.  If $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are two sides of a triangle, and $|\vec a|$ is the base of the triangle, then $|\vec b|\sin\theta$ is the height of the triangle.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299352/show-that-the-area-of-a-triangle-is-given-by-this-determinant)